# Is there cli command to list monitors connected by usbc

Tags: linux, command-line, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I'm having permanent problems with multiple monitors connected to my laptop using different usb-c docks. They work most of the time but sometimes start dying and I'm trying to find out why. I tried `lsusb`, which works for for everything except displays.

Is there some command to list recognized displays with their properties? I tried `xrandr --listproviders` but it does not return anything.

I tried to read syslog, kern.log, dmesg but could not find anything useful.

I have thinkpad with 3 big monitors working nicely, but other identical setups fails. I suspect it could be anything from kernel version to hardware settings (video freq should be same) so any help debugging is appeciated.

Comment: Try `get-edid | parse-edid`? Or you might find some info via `grep "Display" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Check out the answers here for other options: https://askubuntu.com/questions/371261/display-monitor-info-via-command-line

Answer (score 0):

get edid did return some information. This is notebook with 4 screens, one built-in and 3 usb, one display is switched to another input.

[image]

Supposed I have some information but no idea how to use it. According https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDID there should be screen resolution etc.

Comment: Try parsing that output with `get-edid | parse-edid` for readable output instead of raw EDID data